# Google Knowledge API not returning Details of Search Query but just displaying a placeholder

Tags: python, google-knowledge-graph, knowledge-graph

When I ran the search Query for "Apple Inc" I am not getting the "detailedDescription" field.

The query :https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?query=Apple+Inc&key=AIzaSyD_6bOqsyts7K1NOUarvvY7CxQ5DzqZI6A&limit=1&indent=True

[image: Response]

The "detailedDescription" : "goog:detailedDescription".

I need to be able to extract the actual description.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: looks like a property extension. When you get the `GET` response try doing something like `response.detailedDescription`

Comment: If you post your API call code I can help you more.

Comment: The API call is the &quot;query&quot; above. You can paste the query in your browser and check.

Comment: It looks like it may be an issue with their API. There are a couple other questions on SO and other websites that state a similar issue.  You may want to submit help ticket.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse , thank you. Will post the ticket.